# Add values on top of bars in barplot Julia

Tags: julia, label, bar-chart, frequency

I have the following barplot in Julia Plots:

```
using DataFrames
using Plots

df = DataFrame(group = ["A", "B"], 
               value = [10, 9])

bar(df[!, "group"], df[!, "value"], legend = :none)
```

Output:

[image]

I would like to show the values of each bar on top of each bar. So in this example, it should show the values 10 for bar A and 9 for bar B. Is there an automatic way for this or should you annotate the values in `Julia` `Plots`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach using `annotate`.

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> using Plots

julia> bar(df.group, df.value, legend = :none)

julia> annotate!(df.group, df.value, df.value, :bottom)
```

[image: bar plot with text annotation above bars]

Answer (score 1):

I found the argument `texts` which can show the value on top on the bars like this:

```
bar(df[!, "group"], df[!, "value"], legend = :none, texts = df[!, "value"])
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it shows the values, but it isn't nicely aligned.